# Using Kivy as a user interface, wanting to monitor IO like a PLC

Tags: io, kivy, plc

I'm wanting to monitor IO and display the status on my Kivy labels.

I know how to update a Kivy label and operate buttons, but I want to show a label status such as "if X input is OFF then display Y output is OFF"

The idea is that I want to constantly monitor these. Maybe 2s delay inbetween read times or greater, but more or less operate similarly to a PLC.

My idea was to create an object that looped over the data on a time basis and when critera was met I could make a call to the main class and update the labels. My issue is that I don't know how to call an object creation after my kivy app has been generated so that I can monitor IO.

If you can help me I would greatly appreciate it. Here is my code:main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import random
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher

class YourWidget(Widget):

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)

    random_number = StringProperty()
    button4status = StringProperty()
    button4statusinput = StringProperty()



    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(YourWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.random_number = str(random.randint(1, 100))
        #self.random_number2 = str(random.randint(1, 100))
        self.button4status = str("Light is OFF")

        def change_text(self):
            self.random_number = str(random.randint(1, 100))

    def change_text2(self, button4statusinput):
            #self.random_number2 = str(random.randint(1, 100))
        self.button4status = str(button4statusinput)

    def button4pressed(self):
        #GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        #GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_OFF
        #GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(21, False)
        button4statusinput = "Light is ON"

    def button4released(self):
        #GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_OFF)
        #GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(21, True)
        button4statusinput = "Light is OFF"

    def ButtonMonitor(self):
        GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_OFF)
        if GPIO.input(6) == RPI.GPIO.HIGH:
            GPIO.output(21, True)

    #def make_buttontester1():
        #pass

    def ExitApp(Self):
        GPIO.cleanup()
        App.get_running_app().stop()

#class buttontester1(object):
        #GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        #GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)
        #GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_OFF)

        #while True:
            #if GPIO.input(6) == GPIO.LOW:
                #GPIO.output(16, True)
            #if GPIO.input(6) == GPIO.HIGH:
                #GPIO.output(16, False)





class YourApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return YourWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    YourApp().run()
```

your.kv

```
#:kivy 1.9.2

<YourWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10
            Button:
                id: btn1
                text: "Change Text"
                on_release: root.change_text()
                size_hint: 1, 1

            Button:
                id: btn2
                text: "Exit App"
                on_release: root.ExitApp()
                size_hint: 1, 1

            Label:
                id: lbl1
                font_size: 70
                text:root.random_number
                size_hint: 1, 1

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10
            Button:
                id: btn3
                text: "Change Text"
                on_release: root.change_text2()
                size_hint: 1, 1

            Button:
                id: btn4
                text: "Press to Light LED"
                on_press: root.button4pressed()
                on_press: root.change_text2(str("Light Is ON"))
                on_release: root.button4released()
                on_release: root.change_text2(str("Light is OFF"))
                size_hint: 1, 1

            Label:
                id: lbl2
                font_size: 70
                text:root.button4status
                size_hint: 1, 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm wanting something like my button1tester class to run in a loop and evaluate IO for example. Is there anyway to do this in parallel to the kivy app where it functions as it normally does but also there is like a looping object in the background?

Comment: You should use a thread for this kind of background task. If the task doesn't take long, you can also use `Clock.schedule_interval`.

Comment: Thanks using a thread worked really well here. Now I have an issue where I need to reach my functions from the thread. Doh!